# Download and extract archive without archive save

Tags: windows, firefox, zip, extract, rar

### 1. Briefly

I don't find, how I can automatically quick extract `zip` or/and `rar` archives after loading for Windows 10. It would be nice any gratis solution. Firefox solution is preferable.

---

### 2. Settings

For example, I have [**a link**](https://7themes.su/stuff/0-0-0-142-20) to `zip` file.

---

### 3. Expected behavior

Example:

I click to link → than automatically: zip-archive download → archive extract to new folder → archive delete.

---

### 4. Did not help

1. Googling,
2. Search addon in [**MozillaAddons**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) site for my Firefox browser,
3. [**JDownloader2**](http://jdownloader.org/home/index) have this feature, but I need to make more steps, even than manually extract and remove archive.
4. I find [**similar question for Linux**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85194), but I don't find, how I can get similar behavior for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If your description of the workflow is acceptable, that is saving the file and starting the extraction, you could check the options of your chosen management program.

As an example WinRAR ([documentation](https://www.winrar-france.fr/winrar_instructions_for_use/source/html/HELPExtractAdvOptions.htm)) supports the deletion of the successfully extracted archive in the advanced options.

[image: WinRAR delete files after extraction dialog]

If you want to do it like the Linux solution you would have to do some more work.

Comment: I'm sorry, can WinRAR download files from remote servers? Thanks.

Comment: No, but that's not what your initial description said and isn't what the Linux version does either. While it does the download you would still not be clicking a link. If you are willing to script it you would be able to do any kind of thing, especially if you#re willing to save the file on your HDD and that's not also a sudden requirement.